# changing <b> tag style to font-weight normal

Tags: seo, blackhat, css

I am highlighting key words on my web pages using the `<b>` tag. I have set all `<b>` tags to `font-weight: normal` in my global stylesheet and was wondering if this would be considered a 'black hat' technique by search engines? My colleague seems to think so but i'm not too sure as it's just styling. Does anyone know or have an opinion?

Comment: What **Word** tag are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, my formatting didn't work. I'm referring to the bold tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the `<b>` tag but making it look like normal text then this is black hat SEO. The only reason why someone would do this is to manipulate their search engine  rankings. That's a blatant violation of the search engines' terms of service.

Comment: Do you know that for a fact?

Comment: This is SEO 101. While not explicitly mentioned, [this page](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769) covers it quite well. Basically, don't serve up content only for search engines and avoid tricks intended to improve search engine rankings.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but the reason I transformed the style of bold tags to normal weight is for a cosmetic purpose. It wasn't my intention to hide it from the user.

Comment: If the text isn't going to be bold, why use the bold tag at all?

Comment: I understand now. I've set all my b tags to font-weight: bold again. You're right. What is the point in using them if the user can't see them.

Comment: @codemonkey: what's the point doing these kind fo stuff taht is tne best case will give you 0.00000001% of better ranking?!

Answer (score 3):

Semantically the **bold** tag [doesn't mean much](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element) and therefor I wouldn't consider it to be black hat SEO tactics. If however you were to do the same to the **strong** or *em* tags you are definitely abusing their use.

However, it might not be explicitly mentioned but like everyone has been saying it probably won't do your SEO any good. John makes a good point, why would you use it if it isn't for styling? Check [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#text-level-semantics) for more information on the exact semantics of the different tags and choose the right on for your needs.